# how to create auto youtube subscribe link

Tags: php, javascript, youtube

i want to create such a link , when any person click on this link then it redirect to our youtube channel and click automatically subscibe button. (please don't suggest this method  ?sub_confirmation=1 because it shows a confirmation popup).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but it is not possible to create a link that will automatically subscribe a user to your YouTube channel without requiring them to confirm their subscription.

According to YouTube's policies, users must actively confirm their subscription to a channel in order to become a subscriber. This is to ensure that users are fully aware of and have explicitly agreed to receive updates from a channel.

To create a link that will automatically subscribe a user to your YouTube channel when clicked, use the following format:

https://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID

Replace YOUR_CHANNEL_ID with the ID of your YouTube channel. You can find your channel's ID by going to your channel's page on YouTube and looking at the URL. The ID is the string of characters that appears after channel/ in the URL.

For example, if the URL of your channel is https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxj4g4A4pOdOZAEgDZv-QQQ, your channel's ID is UCxj4g4A4pOdOZAEgDZv-QQQ.

So, the subscribe link for your channel would be https://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=UCxj4g4A4pOdOZAEgDZv-QQQ.

When a user clicks on this link, they will be taken to a page where they can confirm their subscription to your channel.

Comment: can we apply javascript on the redirected page like onclick() function on subscription button??

Comment: or can we bypass this confirmation popup message?